# return modified value from a function template error

Tags: c++, templates

My code is something like this:

```
   // ... code

   template <int i>
   int modifyparameter()
   {
     i = i++;
     return i;
   }

   // ... some more code

   int main()
   {
        int answer = modifyparameter<5>();
        cout << answer; //expecting 6
   }
```

But I am getting errors. What have I done wrong?

Comment: When you get errors, always tell us *what* errors you get.

Comment: I suspect the line `i = i++;` is undefined behavior anyway. Increment with `++i;`

Answer (score 3):

`i` is not an `lvalue`, so `i++` is illegal.

`14.1/5` says.

> A non-type non-reference template-parameter  is  not  an  lvalue.   It
>     shall  not  be assigned to or in any other way have its value changed.

Post-increment operator (`++`) requires an `lvalue` as an operand.

Answer (score 3):

`i` is the name of an int *value*, and you cannot modify values. You probably want one of these:

```
template <typename Number>
Number functional(Number x)
{
    return x + 1;
}

template <typename Number>
Number& side_effect(Number& x)
{
    return ++x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
template <int i>
int modifyparameter()
{
  int copy_of_i = i;
  copy_of_i++;
  return copy_of_i;
}
```

There's nothing you can do to modify `i` itself, template parameters are compile-time constants.  However, you could make it act as if I was being modified by using a variable with static lifetime:

```
template <int i>
int modifyparameter()
{
  static int copy_of_i = i;
  copy_of_i++;
  return copy_of_i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While it's not asked for, this seems to cry out for a compile-time solution:

```
template< int I >
struct increment { static const int result = I+1; };

std::cout << increment<41>::result << '\n';
```

That `struct` is what's called a meta-function. Yes, it's a struct, but it's used (at compile-time) like a function: you call it, passing a parameter, and you get back a result. The syntax is hilarious, but that's because nobody actually planned to do this; the possibility was discovered (more or less) by accident.

Doing this at compile-time has the advantage that the result is a compile-time constant and can be used as such:

```
int my_array[increment<7>::result]; // array of 7+1 ints
```

Of course, defining an array like this is nonsense. Just as in run-time algorithms, incrementing is usually just one operation of an algorithm that computes something more complex.